# UIPickerView Margin Left

Tags: swift, uipickerview

For a UIPickerView with a title, I'm looking for a way to provide a left margin to the title. Currently, the first two words seem to be cropped.

I'm using this UIPickerView method to assign title.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    let title = NSAttributedString(string: castProductDetails[row].price, attributes:[.font: FontFamily.Roboto.medium.font(size: 16.0), .foregroundColor: Asset.Colors.primaryText.color] )
    pickerLabel.attributedText = title
    return pickerLabel
}
```

[Adding screenshot for reference.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KgsE9P40YCYAAmJP3yEkiXHYNUdnTRpD/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    
    let margin : CGFloat = 20.0
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = margin
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = margin
    
    let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: yourArrayHere[row])
    title.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle,
                       value: paragraphStyle,
                       range: NSRange(location: 0, length: title.length))
    
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.attributedText = title
    return pickerLabel
}
```